# Copyright breach – how close can I go?

Tags: copyright, criminal-law, contract-law, constitutional-law, copyright-transfer

Recently I was working on usability for a web applicatioin (which I'm not allowed to share :( and the UI ended up looking just like the Gmail. Would there be any copyrights issue if I churn out something similar to Google gmail? Also how do I convince or reason it out with the management?

I have uploaded 2 snapshots so you can have a look.
Standards are meant to be used otherwise what's the point? 
Also I got a reply from another forum: Pablo Picasso once said "Good artists copy, great artists steal."[image]

[image]

Comment: There would be no copyright issues - you are not copying their code - there will probably be patent infringement issues.

Comment: @davidgo: What makes you think there are any patents that he is infringing on?

Comment: Because apple patented "rounded corners" -(I know the reality of that casevisca lot more complex then that). Im not a patentvexpert, butvI know Google have paitented their homepage design - http://www.patentadesign.com/gallery/google-home-page-design-patent.html - I see no reason they would not do something similar with there other large properties.

Comment: There might very well be a derivative works copyright claim as to the layout or even the code depending on how it is put together.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what a coincidence.

If it looks like Gmail, and someone at Google sees it, there is the risk that you are getting sued for copyright infringement. I couldn't possibly judge whether you are *guilty* of copyright infringement, but you can get *sued* (which costs time and money), and there is the possibility that a court *decides against you* (costs a lot of money), whether you committed copyright infringement or not.

How do you convince your management: You don't. It's their decision. You tell them honestly what you think the risks are. It's their job to make the decision, possibly after consulting a lawyer. Whether they want to throw your work away (or possibly make you change it), or whether they accept a risk of being sued, it's their decision.